# Flatten Rust struct with extra `id` property back to TypeScript single object in return of wasm-bindgen function

Tags: typescript, rust, wasm-bindgen

I am using wasm-bindgen to pass data from rust code to an existing TypeScript codebase. In my TypeScript I have two interfaces, a `InvoiceSchema` and an `InvoiceWithId`. The only difference is that `InvoiceWithId` also has an `id` property.

```
interface InvoiceSchema { billTo: string, email: string }
interface InvoiceWithId extends InvoiceSchema { id: string }
```

I understand in Rust, you can't inherit from another struct and add the extra `id` property so I have created a struct:

```
struct InvoiceWithId {
  pub id: String
  pub schema: InvoiceSchema
}
```

At some point I do need to merge this into a single object for the existing TypeScript code.

How should I convert and pass these objects back to TypeScript so the `id` property is part of the base object? i.e.

```
{ id: string, billTo: string, email: string }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this using the `serde-wasm-bindgen` crate, which lets you serialize Rust structs to JavaScript values using their serde `Serialize` implementation.

```
#[derive(serde::Serialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
struct InvoiceSchema {
    pub bill_to: String,
    pub email: String,
}

#[derive(serde::Serialize)]
struct InvoiceWithId {
    pub id: String,
    #[serde(flatten)]
    pub schema: InvoiceSchema,
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
fn get_invoice_with_id() -> JsValue {
    let invoice_with_id = InvoiceWithId { ... };

    serde_wasm_bindgen::to_value(&invoice_with_id).unwrap()
}
```

Comment: thanks, this gets me 90% there. It returns a JavaScript `Map` rather than an object. It looks like this is a limitation of serde losing type information mentioned here: https://github.com/cloudflare/serde-wasm-bindgen/issues/9.

Comment: @DaveTaylor Ah, unfortunate.